# OpenCV3 - Install extra-modules ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone !

I know there's already a post about this subject : http://answers.ros.org/question/229246/how-to-build-opencv-extra-module-while-opencv-is-installed-with-ros/ but there's no answer.

OpenCV3 is included with ROS Kinetic.
Is there a way to install opencv extra-modules while opencv is already installed  ?

Thank you for your help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256277/opencv3---install-extra-modules-ros-kinetic/) by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2017-03-06

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Matt,

the OpenCV package that is installed with ROS already include the extra-modules with exception of the
neural networks I guess. Have a look at the opencv3 ros package. The question how to compile and
install only the extra-modules is a question I also interested in. But until now I get now answer for it, too.

best

Manuel

---

Originally posted by [Mondi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22211/mondi/) with karma: 51 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0